# ("") printing not working in python

Tags: python

hi i have tryed a code that will make a bigger code for me.

```
a = 000000000000000000000000
while a <= 999999999999999999999999(

    ab + 1

    print ("""
     send, {enter}
     send, {tab}
     send, {tab}
     send, {tab}
     send, {tab}
     send, {tab}
     send, {tab}
     send, {tab}
     send, {del}
     send, {del}
     send, {del}
     send, {del}
     send, {del}
     send, {del}
    """)
    )
```

but the print is still not working i have tryed it in diffrent versions of python using the print "hello world" and print ("hello world") but still no result.

its probably something really simple.
thx

Comment: just read the code over its supposed o be a + 1 but that bit wasent the problem.

Comment: I think the syntax is wrong isn't it?

Comment: The problem is you are *ignoring errors*. Read the error messages - and report them as appropriate - instead of just defaulting to "not working". (That code contains no less than one syntax error and one semantic error which would result in an exception.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parentheses on the `while` loop are not Python syntax, try:

```
while a <= 999...: # colon, not parenthesis
    a += 1 # not just a + 1, you need to assign back to a too
    print(...)
```

Or, more Pythonic:

```
for a in range(999...):
    print(...)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! i had a couple of errors after but i managed to fix them thank you thank you thank you